# Question detail page not working in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I created all-question component it is visible but when i click on particular question view that redirect to that id but not got details on the id page. here i attached some files,

1. Admin Service file
2. Model file
3. Detail question component file
4. Detail question ts file
5. All question component file
6. All question ts file

**admin.service.ts** - this is admin service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Admin } from "../model/admin";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminService {
  private ROOT_URL =  "http://localhost:3300/questions";

  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json")
                              
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getQuestion(): Observable<Admin[]> {
    return this.http.get<Admin[]>(this.ROOT_URL);
  } 
  getQue(id: string){
    return this.http.get<Admin>(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${id}`);
  }

  addQue(admin){
    return this.http.post<any>(this.ROOT_URL, admin, this.httpOptions);
  }
}



**model=>admin.ts**  - this is model file

export interface Admin {
    description: String,
    // alternatives: String
    alternatives: [
        {
            text: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            isCorrect: {
                type: Boolean,
                required: true,
                default: false
            }
        }
    ]
}


**que-detail.comp.html** - this is question detail component file

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4>Question: {{admin.description}}</h4>
        <h4>Options: {{admin.alternatives}}</h4>
    </div>
</div>


**que-detail.comp.ts**  - this is question details ts file

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Admin } from '../model/admin';
import { AdminService } from '../service/admin.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-question-detail',
  templateUrl: './question-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./question-detail.component.css']
})
export class QuestionDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  id: string;

  admin: Admin;

  adminSub$: Subscription;

  constructor(private adminService: AdminService, private route: ActivatedRoute ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
    this.adminSub$ = this.adminService.getQue(this.id).subscribe(admin => {
      this.admin = admin;
    });
  }

}


**all-que.comp.html** - this is all question component file

<div class="card bg-dark text-white my-4 dashboard-bg">
  <div class="card-body text-center">
    <ul class="questions" *ngIf="admin$ | async as questions">
      <li *ngFor="let question of questions">
          <h4 class="card-title my-2">{{question.description}}</h4>
          <h5 *ngFor="let x of question.alternatives">{{x.text}}</h5>
          <a [routerLink]="question._id">View</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


**all-que.comp.ts** - this is all question ts file

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Admin } from '../model/admin';
import { AdminService } from '../service/admin.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-question',
  templateUrl: './all-question.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-question.component.css']
})
export class AllQuestionComponent implements OnInit {

  admin$: Observable<Admin[]>;

  constructor(private adminService: AdminService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.admin$ = this.adminService.getQuestion()
  }

}
```

Comment: where have you defined the 'question' variable in 'que-detail.comp.ts' ?

Comment: not defined can you explain?

Comment: You need to define a variable inside your .ts file in order to use it inside template. From your code it seems that you are storing the information inside the 'admin' variable, so you need to use the admin variable in order to access that information inside template.

Comment: Change the 'question' variable inside template to 'admin'. Like this - {{admin.description}} && {{admin.alternatives}}.

Comment: i did try this but not get output
i apply as below on component.html template
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4>{{admin.description}} && {{admin.alternatives}}</h4>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: are you sure you are getting right data inside your subscription. can you do console.log(admin) inside the 'this.adminService.getQue(this.id).subscribe(admin' function and check if you are getting right data.

Comment: yes i did console as , this.adminSub$ = this.adminService.getQue(this.id).subscribe(admin => {
     
      this.admin = admin;
      console.log(admin)
    });
 but not get anything in console at detail page.

Comment: This means your service is failing to obtain data from backend. Add an error callback to your subscribe method and check what error you are getting from the bakend.

Comment: i added as,

    this.adminSub$ = this.adminService.getQue(this.id).subscribe(admin => {
     
      this.admin = admin;
      (err) => {console.log(err)}
      // console.log(admin)
    });

Is this right? or can you show eg.  not get anything in console

Comment: do it like this: this.adminSub$ = this.adminService.getQue(this.id).subscribe(admin => { this.admin = admin;  // console.log(admin) },(err) => {console.log(err)});

Comment: still not get anything in console.

Comment: It would be better if you can create a Sandbox working example.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question Details Component should be like,

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
    <h4>Question: {{admin.description}}</h4>
    <h5>Options:</h5>
    <ng-container *ngFor="alternative of admin.alternatives">
    <h6>{{alternative.text}}</h6>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

You are just using the undefined `questions` variable ig.

Comment: Adarsh Thakur,

I applied your code on detail component but i not get output.
error - Property 'question' does not exist on type 'QuestionDetailComponent'
<ng-container *ngFor="alternative  of question.alternatives">

i am not get your below point,
**You are just using the undefined questions variable ig. 
so can you explain in detail. 

thanks

Comment: My Bad @Visu I edited the answer. use `admin` instead of `questions` in `*ngFor`.

Comment: ya i already did this but nothing happened.